# Programmatically running a stored procedure in Redshift

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, plpgsql, aws-glue

Is there a way to run a stored procedure on a schedule? I have a series of updates/inserts and an unload that I would want to run programmatically. I haven’t written those queries as a stored procedure yet because I want to first see if it can be run / called programmatically or if it’s something that glue would have to do? Where can I look to figure out how to do this?

I know that stored procedures in Redshift are very new. I'm currently executing my code in Pycharm Professional and I've been able to create and run a simple stored procedure.

My updates & inserts (before writing them as a stored procedure) are very similar to the formats specified in [Performing a Merge operation by specifying a column list - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/merge-specify-a-column-list.html).

Any help will be much appreciated? Are there any references that you could share?

Comment: check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64775753/how-to-run-arbitrary-ddl-sql-statements-or-stored-procedures-using-aws-glue

Answer (score 2):

You would need to run some code externally that triggers the stored procedure.

For example, an AWS Lambda function can be configured to run on a schedule. It could then use `psycopg2` to connect to the Amazon Redshift cluster and execute an SQL command to run the stored procedure.

Alternatively, if you have Amazon EC2 instances running, you could use a `cron` job to run a `psql` command that connects and runs an SQL command.